# Python3 - Inserting the value of a variable into another variables command

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, variables

I'm creating a basic transcoder in Python3, but this question is not about transcoding, more about variables within commands, hence the reason I'm only including the information that is necessary. 
This line extracts the text from the combobox/dropdown menu and can either be 400k 700k or 1500k:

```
vbit = str(self.ui.comboBox1.currentText())
```

^ This bit works fine.
I have this bit of code which is capable of passing an argument to ffmpeg and transcoding a file.

```
cmd = '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v 400k -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'
```

^ this work when I write the value as 400k within the code, so again there are no issues with this bit.

Here is my issue- I want the value of `vbit` to be inserted into the command above where the 400k is, depending on what value is contained within vbit (i.e. 400k, 700k or 1500k). I'm trying to insert the value of vbit into the line. I've tried this but its not working.

```
cmd = '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v " + vbit + " -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'
```

This is a question essentially about the right syntax for inserting a variable into a line of code.

Comment: Why not use the same `%s` interpolation you're (presumably) using for the other values as well…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either open and close your string literals appropriately:

```
vbit = '400k'
cmd = '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v ' + str(vbit) + ' -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'
#  '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v 400 -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'
```

or use string formatting:

```
vbit = '400k'
cmd = '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v {} -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'.format(vbit)
#  '-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v 400 -b:a 260k "%s.mp4"'
```

Comment: ok, thanks I used your first option and its worked nicely. Can I just ask, I also tried using double quotes around `+ str(vbit)` just as an experiment and it failed. Why does it need to be single quotes out of interest (apologies i'm new to Python)?

Comment: @treetop the quotes aren't surrounding  `+ str(vbit)`. They surround the string literal `'-i "%s" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -b:v '`.